# How to make the line follow the mouse on hover, but also have a circle follow the path with D3.js v6?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

- I followed this example  [d3react-multiline-chart][1]  which uses D3.js v 5.15.0.
- the problem `const [x] = d3.mouse(anchorEl);` is not working with D3.js v6.7.0.
- I want to convert the following function using `d3.pointer(event)` so the line follows the mouse on hover, but also have a circle follow the path.

```
    const followPoints = React.useCallback(() => {
        const [x] = d3.mouse(anchorEl);
        const xDate = xScale.invert(x);
        const bisectDate = d3.bisector((d) => d.date).left;
        let baseXPos = 0;
    
        // draw circles on line
        d3.select(ref.current)
          .selectAll(".tooltipLinePoint")
          .attr("transform", (cur, i) => {
            const index = bisectDate(data[i].items, xDate, 1);
            const d0 = data[i].items[index - 1];
            const d1 = data[i].items[index];
            const d = xDate - d0?.date > d1?.date - xDate ? d1 : d0;
            if (d.date === undefined && d.value === undefined) {
              // move point out of container
              return "translate(-100,-100)";
            }
            const xPos = xScale(d.date);
            if (i === 0) {
              baseXPos = xPos;
            }
    
            let isVisible = true;
            if (xPos !== baseXPos) {
              isVisible = false;
            }
            const yPos = yScale(d.value);
    
            onChangePosition(d, i, isVisible);
    
            return isVisible
              ? `translate(${xPos}, ${yPos})`
              : "translate(-100,-100)";
          });
    
        drawLine(baseXPos);
        drawContent(baseXPos);
        drawBackground();
      }, [
        anchorEl,
        drawLine,
        drawContent,
        drawBackground,
        xScale,
        yScale,
        data,
        onChangePosition
      ]);
```

- I tried this code but it didn't work:

  ```
  d3.select(anchorEl).on("mousemove.axisY", (event) => {
    [x] = d3.pointer(anchorEl); //.mouse()
  });
  ```

```
 
 


  [1]: https://codesandbox.io/s/d3react-multiline-chart-version-6-separate-components-tooltip-forked-ndf2j?file=/src/components/Tooltip.js:2736-4032
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code:

```
d3.select(anchorEl).on("mousemove.axisY", (event) => {
  [x] = d3.pointer(anchorEl); //.mouse()
});
```

replace `d3.pointer(anchorEl)` with `[event.layerX]`;

It should work for **D3 V6**.

Comment: thanks for your reply you can put all the code because it didn't work for me.

Comment: Please provide a working snippet or a fiddle, so I will be able to fix it in your code. Anyway, it's exacly the part `d3.select(anchorEl).on("mousemove.axisY", (event) => {
  [x] = d3.pointer(anchorEl); //.mouse()
});` where you should replace `d3.pointer(...` with `event.layerX`

Comment: this is the Example https://codesandbox.io/s/d3react-multiline-chart-version-6-separate-components-tooltip-forked-ndf2j?file=/src/components/Tooltip.js:2736-4032

Comment: @DevM I've updated the answer to be more clear

Comment: Your sandbox uses version 5: `"d3": "5.15.0"` - That's what I see in package.json

Comment: yes, I'm tring to make it work with d3.js v6.7.0

Comment: Excellent, now change your sandbox accordingly... One more point, you need to use `[event.layerX]` instead of `event.layerX` because you treat it as an array

Comment: I can hover the Dates but the line does not move

Comment: It works here with V6 (2 fixes in tooltip.js and axis.js): https://codesandbox.io/s/d3react-multiline-chart-version-6-separate-components-tooltip-forked-jwn3j

Comment: ty, It worked. 
I just need to move all code into the .on ("mousemove.axisX", (event) => {...}